# TypeError with d3js tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typeerror

In the d3js [tree sample](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083), I tried to move the call to update outside the d3.json function.  When I did that, I get :

> TypeError: d is undefined

Here is the code (the function here is slightly different from the link to the example).  Notice that I moved the call to update outside the d3.json function.  Note that root is a global variable.

```
  d3.json("../data/flare.json", function(json) {   
     root = json;   
     root.x0 = height / 2;   
     root.y0 = 0;

    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
      }   
    }

   root.children.forEach(collapse);   
   // move this out   
   // update(root); 
});

update(root);

function update(source) {.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3.json` is an asynchronous call. This means that the call will return immediately, but the code in the handler won't run until later. In your case, this means that `root` is not defined (or empty) when you're calling `update(root)`.

In short, you *have* to call `update(root)` from inside the callback of `d3.json`. While there are a few possibilities to make it work outside of the callback, those are much more involved and complex.

Comment: Lars Kotthoff can you share the other ways to make the function call work outside the callaback.  I can see it works when I call it from an html element, i.e., in response to an event.  I am not sure if I can generate an event from javascript

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) explains how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We can't use the root variable to outside `function` ,because root is the local variable for that function.If you want to use outside ,you will make root as the `global varible` for save that json;

```
var root;
    d3.json("../data/flare.json", function(json) {   
     root = json;   
     root.x0 = height / 2;   
     root.y0 = 0;

    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
      }   
    }

   root.children.forEach(collapse);   
   // move this out   
   // update(root); 
});



function update(source) {.....
```

Comment: I should have mentioned 'root' is a global variable

Comment: you can declare root as global variable,but one problem may with the above code since d3.json() function is asynchronous by default.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294363/variable-scope-in-d3-javascript