# Passing variable from Server side to client side JavaScript Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, ejs

index.js

```
var outputFilename = 'C:/askhere/public/javascripts/data.json';
                    fs.writeFile( outputFilename, JSON.stringify(json_obj), "utf8", function(err) {
                        if(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Jobs Data updated in " + outputFilename + " file.");
                        }
                    });
res.render('graph',{uname:req.session.userName,gdata:JSON.stringify(json_obj)});
```

graph.ejs

```
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/graph.js">

                    </script>
```

graph.js

```
            /*var data = [{"label":"1990", "value":16},
    {"label":"1991", "value":56},
    {"label":"1995", "value":16},
];    var data;
    d3.json("data.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error) {return console.log(error);}
        else {data = json; console.log("data updated in graph.js");}
    });
```

Now this code getting "data" update from server in graph.js file but i cant see result in graph.ejs file

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 d3.json('http://domain.com/data.json', function(data) {
     // actual logic...
});
```

to access data served as json from the server.

Otherwise you can also add an inline script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var data = <%=gdata%>;
</script>
```

Side note : you can't have inline script with src attributes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/graph.js">
    var data = <%=gdata%>; // This code will be discarded
</script>
```

Also, i suggest that you read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294363/variable-scope-in-d3-javascript), which may actually be your underlying problem.

Comment: /*var data = [{"label":"1990", "value":16},
    {"label":"1995", "value":16},
];*/
var data;
d3.json("data.json", function(error, json) {
    if (error) {return console.log(error);}
    else {data = json; console.log("data updated in graph.js");}
});
data.json file is updated but there are no results 
Graph : <%=gdata%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/graph.js">
</script>

Comment: @Shah038 what do you mean by "there are no results" ?

Comment: i cant see the result of 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/graph.js"> </script>
in graph.ejs , but when i use old data variable i can see result graph.

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual d3.js code ? the one creating the graph

Comment: Your problem is that you can't just assign `data = json`, you have to keep all your code inside the `function(error, json) {}` callback