# Typescript not loading the data first using D3 csv

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have gone through link: [variable scope in d3 javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294363/variable-scope-in-d3-javascript) as my data was not getting loaded in the variable at first.
I tried the following code:

```
let train;
// d3.csv("training.csv", function(data){train = data;});
function myFunc(data) {
    train = data;
}

d3.csv("training.csv", function (data) {
    var csv = data;
    myFunc(csv);
});
```

Still I am getting the variable as `undefined` when I tried to log it through `console.log()`
See the following image:
[image: output image]

Please let me know what I can do. Have I been missing something? Please suggest me what I can do to avoid this issue.

Comment: Where in the above code is your `console.log`?  Because `d3.csv` is *async* it must be in the `d3.csv` callback or some function called from it.

Comment: But I am storing the csv data in the variable `train` and that variable I am fetching in the anther file where I am assigning it to different process. In that file I tried to log the `train' variable. even if I put this whole code in the same file still I get the same issue.

Comment: Same file, different files doesn't matter.  All processing on that variable needs to stem from the `d3.csv` callback.  It'll only reliably be available there...