# d3 v4 map becomes empty unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, csv, dictionary, d3.js

I'm trying to read in data from a csv and form a map with key = state abbreviation and value = the frequency of that state in the data.

The code I have correctly creates a map and reads in the data, and I can `console.log(MAP)` correctly.

However, when I try to iterate through the map using `.each` or `.entries()`, the map is empty. `map.size()` returns 0.

```
var statesData = d3.map();
d3.csv("temp-data.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    data.forEach(function(row) {
        if (statesData.has(row.state) == false) {
          statesData.set(row.state, 1);
        }
        else {
          statesData.set(row.state, statesData.get(row.state) + 1);
        }
    });
});
console.log(statesData);
console.log(statesData.size());
statesData.each(function(d) {
  console.log("value: " + d);
});
```

Output:

```
{}
"$AZ": 1
​
"$CA": 1
​
"$CO": 1
​
"$IA": 1
​
"$KS": 2
​
"$OK": 1
​
"$OR": 1
​
"$PA": 1
​
"$WA": 1
​
<prototype>: Object { constructor: Map(), has: has(), get: get()
, … }
0
```

[image]
A picture is also attached for clarification.

`temp-data.csv`:

```
id,state,
3,WA
4,OR
5,KS
8,CA
9,CO
11,OK
13,AZ
15,KS
16,IA
17,PA
```

So it seems as though the map has data within it, but when I call `.size()` it returns 0 (which explains why the `.each()` method doesn't show any output.

I honestly don't understand why this is occurring. I tried reading the docs https://devdocs.io/d3~4/d3-collection#map but it don't understand why I can `console.log(MAP)` fine but not iterate through it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

[variable scope in d3 javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294363/variable-scope-in-d3-javascript)

The `d3.csv` is an asynchronous request, so all code that depends on the data provided by that function should be within that scope.

This explains why the size of `statesData` outside of the `d3.csv` scope is 0.

The following:

```
var statesData = d3.map();
d3.csv("temp-data.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    data.forEach(function(row) {
        if (statesData.has(row.state) == false) {
          statesData.set(row.state, 1);
        }
        else {
          statesData.set(row.state, statesData.get(row.state) + 1);
        }
    });

    console.log(statesData.size())
});
```

Correctly outputs `9`.